# What are elasticsearch indices?

Tags: elasticsearch

They are not mentioned in [ES glossary](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/glossary.html).

What is their relationship to other ES entities (shards / nodes / indexes)  ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indices is the plural of index. If you have more than one index you call them indices.
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/index

Answer (score 3):

**Indices** are equivalent to databases in Relational DBMS. Just like Relational Database has schema, ES **index** has **mapping**.

**Shards**   => **index** is broken into shards (in order to distribute them and scale)

**Replicas** => copies of the **shards** (provide reliability if a node is lost)

I hope the following diagram(taken from [Rafal Kuc's slides](http://www.slideshare.net/kucrafal/scaling-massive-elastic-search-clusters-rafa-ku-sematext?ref=http://prayag-waves.blogspot.com/)) demonstrates the relationship between ES Cluster, Index, Node and Shards.

[image: ES diagram]

Also, there's a nice stackoverflow post [Shards and replicas in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15705989/432903) by [@javanna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633239/javanna)

Comment: I know what is an index/shard/replica. Just not being a native English speaker messed me up. Thank you all for your minuses.

Comment: @Bax Im a native english speaker and all this time I thought and index and indice were different things. I'm 32........... LLOOLL

Comment: Elastic Search recommends to have replica shards in different nodes , but the diagram shows shards and replica shards in same node, what will happen if your node fails for some reason ?

Comment: `Shard 1` in Node1 has `Replica shard 1` in Node2. Similarly `R3` for `Shard 3` is on `Node 3` which is what elasticsearch recommends as you said - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/replica-shards.html