# Understanding Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

Sorry to say this but ES' documentation ( http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html ) is confusing me.

Thanks to the glossary I understand the terms for database, table and row but I have read substantial sections of the documentation and I cannot find answers to:

- Why do I need do to add `number_of_shards` and `number_of_replicas` to index creation? I did look here http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html but ironically it leaves those two settings out `:/`
- How can I have 3 shards with 2 replicas? If the glossary is anything to go by shouldn't that be impossible considering that a shard is "is a single Lucene instance"?
- If I add more nodes later how can I change these values to span the new nodes?
- How does sharding work in ES?
- How does replica sets work in ES?
- How can I manage sharding? I understand it is auto join ( http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html#cluster-name ) but how do I define the difference between replicas and shards?
- How can I manage replica sets? I.e. how do I add replicas, promote primaries etc?

For reference I read these links first:

- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/glossary.html
- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html

If that information exists in the documentation then I would be very grateful if you can point me towards it.

**Edit:**

I am also unsure how auto-discovery works on a distributed network. Short if pinging every public network around how does it connect to the right one that could possibly be on the other side of the world?

Comment: This answer goes a fair way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694724/shards-and-replicas-in-elasticsearch

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please see below for answers to your points.

> - Why do I need do to add number_of_shards and number_of_replicas to index creation? I did look here
>     http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html
>     but ironically it leaves those two settings out :/

You don't "have" to, but you probably should in especially will want to in production. The default is five shards and one replication.

The number of replications defined is just the number of times your entire index is replicated throughout all of the nodes in your elasticsearch cluster. Think of it as being multiple read copies of a RDBMS database (but in this case, we read and write all copies).

A shard is the number of times I split up, or shard, an index. So, I can have an index with a single shard, or I can have an index with multiple shards. This is similar in concept to sharding a RDBMS database by primary key, but not identical.

So, the total number of shards you will have in an index is the product of number_of_shards and number_of_replicas.

When you do a search, elasticsearch will distribute your search to all possible nodes containing the shards in your index and aggregagate the result for you. You can think of this as a map/ reduce where the map is sending the search out to each shard and the reduce is collecting the results.

Also, you can change the replication number_of_replicas at any time, but you can never change the number_of_shards. This must be set at index creation.

> - How can I have 3 shards with 2 replicas? If the glossary is anything to go by shouldn't that be impossible considering that a
>     shard is "is a single Lucene instance"?

I think the above mostly answers this, but it's important to remember that elasticsearch is primarily a distributed computing solution to search. We are splitting the work up to multiple shards and possibly machines.

> - If I add more nodes later how can I change these values to span the new nodes?

Once the cluster is aware of another node in the cluster, no other action is needed by you. The settings propagate throughout the cluster on their own. In your above example of three shards and two replicas, if you had two nodes initially and added a third, each node will have on average two shards per node, this shard movement happens without your intervention (again, provided the cluster is aware of the new node)

> - How does sharding work in ES?

See above

> - How does replica sets work in ES?

See above

> - How can I manage sharding? I understand it is auto join ( http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html#cluster-name ) but how do I define the difference between replicas and shards?

You don't have to "manage" it actively. As stated earlier, sharding and everything else you define at index creation, is propagated to new nodes within the cluster.

You define replicas and shards like this:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": 20,
            "number_of_replicas": 1
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "some_type": {
            "properties": {
                "some_field": {
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> - How can I manage replica sets? I.e. how do I add replicas, promote primaries etc?

You do that through the update indices API, documentation for this specific case is found on there site here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html

I just noticed your edit, please see below:

> - I am also unsure how auto-discovery works on a distributed network.

In the YML config file you set the unicast like this:

```
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ip.add.r.ess", "ip.add.r.ess"]
```

The middle setting is an important setting, but I commented it out here. That number should always be number of (master nodes / 2) +1. This is to avoid split brain situations. Generally I set all nodes to master eligible.

These settings are for unicast, which is what I think you are going for with your question and not multicast.

Comment: So if I understand you right a shard is not a copy it is the data, a range of the id, (similar to SQL and MongoDB in this respect), but a primary shard cannot be split again which means if I wanna distribute my read further I have to recreate. You get the answer vote for the detailing of all the settings and that, thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

In short, an index is broken into shards. Shards can be replicated, meaning multiple copies of the same shard can exist in the same cluster. So if an index has 3 shards and 2 replica's, that means you have nine shards in total of which six are replicas of the three master shards.

ES, will try to balance shards and their replica's across the cluster so that if a node goes down it can fail over from the master shards on that node to replicas. This can confuse some people: a master in elastic search refers to shards, not the actual node. So a single node can have a mix of replica's and master shards.

If you come from the lucene world, a lucene index is not the same thing as an elastic search index. An elastic search index is a logical group of indexed documents with types, mappings and documents. More or less the same as a database schema. A lucene index on the other hand is a group of several files that contains indexed data. When Elastic search creates indexes, what it does is create several lucene indexes (one for each field and shard) and when it replicates, it is basically copying the files of these lucene indices around.

You can't change the number of shards for an index but you can change the number of replicas. Typically what you do when you need to have more shards is create a new index and reindex the data.

In terms of shard management beyond deciding on the number of shards, there's not much to manage by default and ES is pretty good coordinating things by itself, There are a ton of options you can fiddle with once you gain a bit better understanding of how it works. Defaults are pretty OK for most. In terms of cluster management, you can do a lot via the API in terms of shutting down nodes in a controlled way, using index aliases, changing number of replica's, etc.

As for autodiscovery, ES uses local network multicast by default. You can switch to unicast and you probably want to change the default clustername to prevent accidents (had some fun in coffeeshops with unintended clusters forming). You probably don't want to cluster globally. I don't see that ending well.

Comment: Yeah you second paragraph was one bit that really confused me, I thought of physical machines like in MongoDB, bit a bummer I have to reform the index if I get a serious spike and need to distribute my reads further. Heh Yeah the problem with cluster names and broadcasting was my thought too. +1

Comment: You can use aliases to mitigate the fixed number of shards/index problem. This allows you to query a group of indices as one index when querying. For example logstash uses this to create new indices (and shards) every day/week/month. This provides you horizontal scalability and there are some out there who use this at petabyte scale with hundreds of nodes. The clustering is not so much of a problem and more an abundance of choice. The default merely provides convenient behavior in a private network but you can configure it differently if you don't like it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a quite incident that about 80% of your questions are answered in the **Video Presentation given by *Shay Banon*** (The creater of ElastiSearch). Though this presentation has much more than you can find anywhere else. Hope this helps.

```
  http://www.infoq.com/presentations/ElasticSearch
```

This video is a bit low-resolution, so if you want code shown in presentation follow this

```
  https://github.com/kimchy/talks/tree/master/2011/wsnparis
```