# Elasticsearch replica auto undertake shard

Tags: elasticsearch

Below I have 2 nodes in two servers. 2 indexes each. The indexes are distributed in 2 shards and 1 replica set.

"Thor" node had a downtime so I "Iron_man" took over. That's fine.

As you can see events_v1 is an index created before the downtime and venue_v1 was created after the downtime. Shouldn't "Thor" after being back alive take over one shard automatically in the same way as it handles the newly created venue index?

If yes how should I configure the settings?

[image]

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694724/shards-and-replicas-in-elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

You need not to configure anything for above scenario.Because Elasticsearch's default behavior is same as you requested.if you create replica for a shard in same node is not allocated to query.If you add new node means your replica shard will be allocated in newly created node.

for more information [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpZ6ZajygDY)

Comment: Can't disagree with you. That's exactly the behavior I [expected](http://chrissimpson.co.uk/elasticsearch-yellow-cluster-status-explained.html) but for some reason my cluster has decided not rebalance events_v1 between the nodes. I'll better watch the video when I have time. PS: Pacific Rim had some ugly v-fx.