# what do"yellow" and "red" state exactly mean in es2unix?

Tags: elasticsearch

Es2unix,one of the elasticsearch's monitor tool.There are some states while es2unix monitoring elasticsearch,such as red or yellow,to present the cluster's health.

I want to know what the exact state can be called red or yellow.Is it related to CPU used rate?or memory used rate?

PS:If you could recommend some book about elasticsearch for a newer like me,I will thank you much.

Comment: not only book,good article also ok.thanks

Comment: Better Explained by @javanna in the following link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694724/shards-and-replicas-in-elasticsearch>

Comment: thanks.It's more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status `red`, `yellow` or `green` isn't related to the CPU or memory use, it's related to the shards and replicas allocation.

The `yellow` status indicates your cluster is operational (all shards are up) but the replicas are not allocated. In case of failure of one of your node, the data contained in the node's shards will be unavailable.

You will find [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html) the (excellent) ElasticSearch Definitive Guide (along the [reference documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html)).

Later, you could take a look at some of the [webinars](http://www.elasticsearch.org/videos/) and [blog articles](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/) provided by the official website too.