# What does the value in the shard column means?

Tags: elasticsearch

The output of the `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v"` is as follows:

| index | shard | prirep | state | docs | store | ip | node |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test_index | 1 | p | STARTED | 0 | 283b | 127.0.0.1 | Deepaks-MacBook-Pro-2.local |
| test_index | 1 | r | UNASSIGNED | 0 |  |  |  |
| test_index | 1 | r | UNASSIGNED | 0 |  |  |  |
| test_index | 0 | p | STARTED | 2 | 12.5kb | 127.0.0.1 | Deepaks-MacBook-Pro-2.local |
| test_index | 0 | r | UNASSIGNED | 0 |  |  |  |
| test_index | 0 | r | UNASSIGNED | 0 |  |  |  |

What is the meaning of 0/1 in the `shard` column?

Answer (score 0):

### Shards In Elasticsearch

Shard, a subset of data of the whole index, one index data will be saved into shards.

Shard has two parts to it, one primary shard, other one or more replica shards.

You have 2 shards with replica 2

#### First Shard

1. test_index shard 0 which is the primary shard
2. test_index shard 0 which is replica 1 shard - a copy of primary sard
3. test_index shard 0 which is replica 2 shard - a copy of primary sard

#### Second Shard

1. test_index shard 1 which is the primary shard
2. test_index shard 1 which is replica 1 shard - a copy of primary sard
3. test_index shard 1 which is replica 2 shard - a copy of primary sard

Another answer: [Shards and replicas in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694724/shards-and-replicas-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: Sir, shouldn't the first shard have the shard value 0 and the second shard should have shard value 1?

Comment: What about the above question ^ ?

Comment: Correcting my answer, you can call either way there is no harm